# WordPress speed issues

Tags: wordpress, web, optimization, pagespeed

I have been struggling with speed on a WordPress site, I have recently taken over working on the site and I am currently updating plugins and optimizing images, I would like to know if there are any other tips that I can follow to improve the speed of the website? (I am somewhat new to WordPress and would Appreciate any advice!)

Here is a link to the site for reference: http://www.willehonne.club/

Comment: you often get WordPress hosting elsewhere, and these hosts will normally have control over how fast your site loads

Comment: You should contact your hosting, when I loaded your website in Chrome developer tools, there was a 15 second delay at the very first request, before any images or other resources were loaded - basically the browser asked for your website and the server just sat there for 15 seconds before doing anything...that is very unusual and not what you want :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

It is Google's page speed analyzer. Paste your site there and it will inform you of what is causing your site to load slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a caching plugin like WP Rocket or W3TC and optimize your images, CSS, and JS delivery. These simple things will make your website fly.